# Populate mega-dropdown with data

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, drop-down-menu

I found plenty of very nice drop downs to use in my website. (like that one [Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/))

I can't seem to find how I fill the links from a database. I don't want to go to each line and assign it a link manually..

Currently I have some kind of bar that is linked to a data adapter, I tried to change it over to the new design, but I can't bind it to any of this mega menu samples.

I'm using MsSQL server database.

Comment: What does your database table look like? What does your markup look like? How are you doing data access? There are *so many* questions that would need to be answered before answering your main question...

Comment: I just need to know how to bind it to a data-adapter from there I'll know how to work around with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy... I just didn't understood the sample I got :).

I would of delete this question as it won't help anyone searching around but the system wont allow me to do so.

I flagged the question last week but yet got any response.

So I guess I leave it as is and that's all.

Comment: Can you show us complete example along with code & database design so that it can help others also i am also looking for similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to use LINQ to sql then load those results into a datatable. That datatable could then be used as the datasource for your data-adaptor/repeater (or whatever it is you use)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/VIMAL.LAKHERA/LINQResultsetToDatatable06242008042629AM/LINQResultsetToDatatable.aspx

Here is the best (IMO) example from that tutorial

```
var vrCountry = from country in objEmpDataContext.CountryMaster
                        select new {country.CountryID,country.CountryName};

DataTable dt = LINQToDataTable(objEmpDataContext,vrCountry);

public DataTable ToDataTable(System.Data.Linq.DataContext ctx, object query)
{
     if (query == null)
     {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
     }

     IDbCommand cmd = ctx.GetCommand(query as IQueryable);
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
     adapter.SelectCommand = (SqlCommand)cmd;
     DataTable dt = new DataTable("sd");

     try
     {
          cmd.Connection.Open();
          adapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source); 
          adapter.Fill(dt);
     }
     finally
     {
          cmd.Connection.Close();
     }
     return dt;
}
```

You would then bind the `dt` object as the datasource to your control

Hope that helps!